# SDTT error: "A value for the position field is required."

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I'm receiving an error message in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool that indicates I'm missing a value for `position` value of the structured data:

> A value for the `position` field is required.

I can't seem to figure out where it's supposed to reside.  I've tried adding the `position` value in several places.

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "numberOfItems": "5",
    "url": "https://www.mygiftcardsplus.com/buy/merchant/id/Nik#GiftCardItemList ~~~ named location on the page",
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "Product",
            "image": "https://d3bvejazygcenf.cloudfront.net/images/merchant/14597-90617-b16b-5a17/300x190.png",
            "url": "https://www.mygiftcardsplus.com/buy/merchant/id/Nik#25GiftCard ~~~ named location on the page",
            "name": "$25 Nike Gift Card",
            "description": "Get 5% cash back on a $25 Nike Gift Card",
            "offers": {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "price": "25",
                "priceCurrency": "USD"
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Product",
            "image": "https://d3bvejazygcenf.cloudfront.net/images/merchant/14597-90617-b16b-5a17/300x190.png",
            "url": "https://www.mygiftcardsplus.com/buy/merchant/id/Nik#50GiftCard ~~~ named location on the page",
            "name": "$50 Nike Gift Card",
            "description": "Get 5% cash back on a $50 Nike Gift Card",
            "offers": {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "price": "50",
                "priceCurrency": "USD"
            }
        },
                {
            "@type": "Product",
            "image": "https://d3bvejazygcenf.cloudfront.net/images/merchant/14597-90617-b16b-5a17/300x190.png",
            "url": "https://www.mygiftcardsplus.com/buy/merchant/id/Nik#150GiftCard ~~~ named location on the page",
            "name": "$150 Nike Gift Card",
            "description": "Get 5% cash back on a $150 Nike Gift Card",
            "offers": {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "price": "150",
                "priceCurrency": "USD"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Note that you can ignore this error if you don’t care about Google’s search result feature for this data.

Answer (score 1):

The [`position`](https://schema.org/position) can be added to `CreativeWork` or 
`ListItem` items.

If you want to give the position of the products in the list, you can use the `ListItem` type and specify the `Product` via [`item`](https://schema.org/item):

```json
"itemListElement": [

  {
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "item": {
      "@type": "Product"
    }
  },

  {
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "item": {
      "@type": "Product"
    }
  }

]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!